# Google Cloud Platform Trial

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I enabled free trial on Google Cloud Platform and added billing account. Now billing account is closed and I have few questions:

1) Will I be able to use Firebase after trial expire without paid account?

2) Is closing billig acoount means I won't be charged for anything?

All projects are unlinked from billing account.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works:

1. You have a billing account linked to say 5 projects
2. If you want to stop billing on your resources -- you unlink that project
3. Now you want to close the `Billing account itself` -- you will not be charged for any services which fall under [free tier of GCP](https://cloud.google.com/free). i.e. [Firebase's free tier](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) per month
4. One potential issue is that you can not create anything which is charged on the standard rates
5. Once you exhaust your $300 free trial subscription (keep in mind that if you cancel the billing account, you will lose access to the $300), you will still be entitled to per month free tier based on the services you are using.
6. Without enabling billing for a project, you can not create any resources.
7. If you've closed the billing account, you can [re-open it](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#reopen_a_closed_billing_account). A billing account can [cannot be deleted](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#delete_a_billing_account).

Here is a [quote from GCP's doc](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#close_a_billing_account) regarding Closure of a Billing account:

> Closing an active Cloud Billing account stops all billable services in
>   any projects linked to the account, such as running VM instances or
>   storage buckets. Projects that are not linked to an active and valid
>   Cloud Billing account cannot use Google Cloud or Google Maps Platform
>   services that aren't free.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am confused because there is " You will not be billed during your free trial. To keep your projects running after the free trial is up, upgrade to a paid account. ". But when my project isn't linked to this billing account it should works even after trial end, am I right?

Comment: Yes! you need to upgrade to a paid account(this is GCP way of keeping track of billing. no matter free or not). However, you will be billed only when you exceed google's free tier on any services for your paid account. Keep in mind this fact as you might cross the free quota anytime, especially if it's a compute engine you are using.

Comment: So if I won't upgrade the only way to have this project is moving it to another google account?

Comment: What do you mean by "moving it to another google account?" And you need a valid billing account to use the Free Credits. Once those are finished, you will need to pay for the services.

Comment: I mean delete project from current account and add it to new google account

Comment: You can re-enable the billing account as mentioned in Step #7. Changing the ownership of the account will not re-instantiate the trial credits to the project. Trial credits are [offered only once](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial) to a customer. You can also look into the [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free) services, "Always free" services, which allows you limited access to a limited amount of services.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move google account. Your account is type free or not free' as simple as that. Once your 1 year free plan is lapsed you have to upgrade it to normal (non free) billing account.